# Configure gin-gonic session using Redis in Golang

Tags: go, redis, go-gin

I am using gin-gonic in Go and using Redis session feature provided in `github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions` package

```
store, _ := sessions.NewRedisStore(10, "tcp", "localhost:6379", "", []byte("secret"))
router.Use(sessions.Sessions("workino_session", store))
```

How do I control how long these Sessions are stored in Redis?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the README is light on documentation, the [GoDoc docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions) are a little more clear about this.

Note that the gin-gonic sessions package uses [gorilla/sessions](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions) underneath and shares the same options API.

```
// We check for errors.
store, err := sessions.NewRedisStore(10, "tcp", "localhost:6379", "", []byte("secret"))
if err != nil {
    // Handle the error. Probably bail out if we can't connect.
}

// Ref: https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/sessions#Options
store.Options = &sessions.Options{
    MaxAge: 86400,
    Path: "/",
    Secure: true,
    HttpOnly: true,
}

// Use the store once configured.
router.Use(sessions.Sessions("workino_session", store))
```